# mysql query wrong output in finding news from last 4 weeks?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hello i have small project which contains different news.All of the news data are stored in mysql database with the date of news added. Now i want to find a news from last 4 weeks. I have used this query but it seems i am getting wrong output.Any help? Thank you.
Here is the query :

```
SELECT ad_news.datum_archiv, ad_news_texte.headline
FROM ad_news_texte
INNER JOIN ad_news_oe ON ad_news_texte.news_id = ad_news_oe.id_ad_news
INNER JOIN ad_news ON ad_news.id
WHERE DATEDIFF( now( ) , ad_news.datum_archiv ) >28;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last `WHERE` condition

From

```
WHERE DATEDIFF( now( ) , ad_news.datum_archiv ) >28;
```

To

```
WHERE ad_news.datum_archiv between 
curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+24 DAY and curdate()
```

Comment: My head hurts. Isn't this like saying "WHERE 3 BETWEEN 5 AND 1"?

Comment: @Strawberry, you mean I switched them? edited my answer. How about now? Also, consider having a `pain killer` LOL :)

Comment: Hi @Rahul thanks man it works for me :) and bychance my name is also Rahul :)

Comment: @user3702602 (a.k.a Rahul) good to know that. BTW, my actual name is not Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

The `DATEDIFF()` method returns the difference in days between two dates. Your query wants any GREATER than 28 days. But your business logic requires it be from the less four weeks, i.e. LESS THAN or EQUAL TO 28 days difference.

You have a couple of options:

1) Change it to be LESS THAN or EQUAL TO:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF( now( ) , ad_news.datum_archiv ) <= 28;
```

2) Use the `BETWEEN` clause with `DATE_SUB()` method (date subtract):

```
WHERE ad_news.datum_arciv BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 28 DAY)
```

There are several more ways to *skin the cat*, but either of those options should get your desired output.

Comment: Likewise, my nearby comment.

Comment: hi i try to run this but it does not give any rows returned